# Process steps ( Wizard ) in Vertical Format

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, wizard

Want to achieve a process steps wizard pretty much like this one - 
[Process Steps in Horizontal Format](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/process-steps)

But in a vertical format ! Could someone help with CSS modification for making this vertical stacked like a sidebar at left.Or suggest some plugin to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

I modified the CSS I hope you thought something like this. You could see the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2no7b92/).

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.stepwizard-step p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stepwizard-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
  display: table;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
  left: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-order: 0;
}

.stepwizard-step {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Dont know about OP, but certainly helped me